# Loop through anchors in asp control

Tags: asp.net, web, hyperlink, user-controls, anchor

I have asp.net control with the follwoing code. I embed this control into rougly 20 pages  to save myself from updating all pages every time I want to add one more link.

```
<ul>
<li class="first"><a href="GenericNewForm.aspx">Trade blotter entry</a></li>
<li><a href="BlotterList.aspx">Trade blotter list</a></li>
<li><a href="TradeReviewAndUpdate.aspx">Trade review and update</a></li>
<li><a href="TradeVWAPUpdate.aspx">Trade VWAP Update</a></li>
<li><a href="CSATradeBlotter.aspx">CSA Trade blotter entry</a></li>
<li><a href="CSARulesForm.aspx">CSA Rules Screen</a></li>
<li><a href="WebBlotter.aspx">Trade Blotter manager</a></li>
<li><a href="Default.aspx" accesskey="3" title=""><span style="text-transform: uppercase">
    s</span>ign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is to loop through all hyperlinks on Page_Load, find the the anchor that has the url matching the url of the current page and hide the corresponding li.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I ended up passing a parameter into the control to define which link should get hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I have a non ASP.NET solution that might work.  Will jQuery work for you?

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="GenericNewForm.aspx">Trade blotter entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="BlotterList.aspx">Trade blotter list</a></li>
    <li><a href="TradeReviewAndUpdate.aspx">Trade review and update</a></li>
    <li><a href="TradeVWAPUpdate.aspx">Trade VWAP Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="CSATradeBlotter.aspx">CSA Trade blotter entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="CSARulesForm.aspx">CSA Rules Screen</a></li>
    <li><a href="WebBlotter.aspx">Trade Blotter manager</a></li>
    <li><a href="_display" accesskey="3" title=""><span style="text-transform: uppercase">s</span>ign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageName= location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    console.log('current page: ' + pageName);
$("a").each(function(idx, el){
    console.log(el.href);
    var page = el.href.substring(el.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if(page == pageName)
        $(el).addClass('hideMe');
});
```

});

With some css:

```
.hideMe{
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

See fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rodhartzell/QVMxz/

Comment: Thank you very much, Rod. Although I the server code would be better.